# Not able to make the progress bar In Ionic using <div> tag

Tags: html, css

I am making the progress bar in Ionic and for that I have added the 2 divs but the problem is that, I want to show the text in the center and the background color according to the percentage and this is not happening.

This is my **html**:

```
<div class="mydiv2">
      <div class="mydiv21">60%</div>
</div>
```

This is my **css**:

```
div.mydiv2 {
    border: 1px solid #4f1a86;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}

div.mydiv21 {
    padding: 11px;
    width: 60%;
    background: #4f1a86;
}
```

**The output is this:**

[image]

The problem is that the text is not coming in the center. and I want the background to like this only.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are adding text in the center of mydiv21. Do you want it to be in the center of mydiv2?

Comment: @BidhanMajhi. I want the text to be in center of mydiv2 and the background like this only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wrap the "60%" in a span you can do the following.
The outer `mydiv2` gets `position: relative` to be the reference for the span with the percentage.

The span gets `position: absolute` and orientates itself on the mydiv2. To get the the width and the height of mydiv2 it gets the positioning top, right, bottom and left.

The flexbox is to center the textcontent (60%)

```css
div.mydiv2 {
  border: 1px solid #4f1a86;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}

div.mydiv21>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.mydiv21 {
  padding: 11px;
  width: 60%;
  background: #4f1a86;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv2">
  <div class="mydiv21"><span>60%</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want like this, if yes then you need to just add as span with position:absolute; like given below:-

```css
div.mydiv2 {
    border: 1px solid #4f1a86;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
}

div.mydiv21 {
    padding: 20px 11px;
    width: 60%;
    background: #4f1a86;
    line-height: 10px;
}

div.mydiv2 span{ position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px;}
```

```html
  <div class="mydiv2">
    <div class="mydiv21"><span>60%</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have posted 2 same answer.

Comment: @Raghav Welcome, by the way its answered two times due to network issue.